# image width and height seems wrong when getting it with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm not so good at CSS design, but I'm just working on a content display layout for a website. 
I basically wanna make a thin line by putting an image inside a container div. and set all dimension properties as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
       #thinLineWrap{
            width: 510px; 
            height: 3px;
            background-color: #000000;
       }  
       #thinLineWrap img{
           width: 170px;
           height: 3px;
           background-color: #000000;
           margin-top: 0px;
           float:left
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="thinLineWrap">
        <img src="images/thin_line.gif" border="0">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when viewing the output in Chrome inspect, the output result couldn't seem to have the specified sizes as expected, as illustrated in the snapshot below.

[image]

You might also notice that my image width and height became 171px and 4px respectively, unlike what it was set in the stylesheet section.
Any possible mistake I might have done? Why did the image element become 1 pixel bigger than it should be?
any advice would be very appreciated.

**EDIT:**
A copy of the original problematic thin line image is here. Not sure if there could be anything wrong with the image itself.

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-kDRsR493dZU/UMOXRBbty9I/AAAAAAAAAh8/g58GnqQZ3pk/s128/thin_line.gif

Comment: Funny... copy+pasted your code and I don't have that problem in my Chrome. The size is correct.

Comment: i have exact your code in jsFiddle with correct values  check here : http://jsfiddle.net/2qGD2/

Comment: Finally, I found out the root cause of the problem myself. Embarrassingly, my chrome was at over 100% zoom mode, so that made the image stretch unexpectedly. but I just learn that we should not do inspect in developer tool as we're in the zoom mode.

Answer (score 0):

You defined an Img within the #thinlinewrap to have the properties.

```
div#thinLineWrap{
   border:0px;
}

#thinlineWrap img{
   height:3px;
}
```

Might be the code you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i found it out.you'r img inherited it's border from another style ,try overriding it like this :

```
#thinLineWrap img{
           border:none;
           width: 170px;
           height: 3px;
           background-color: #000000;
           margin-top: 0px;
           float:left
       }
```

Comment: Thanks Benham. I tried this, it still gives me the same issue, very weird.